# Making a background image a gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a gradient to my CSS background image. I've found a bunch of other post relating to having a gradient background, with an image sitting on top, but I would like the image itself to be a gradient. I tried this:

```
body {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: rexlia;
background-size: cover;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65))), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url(cubes.jpg) no-repeat;
```

}

All this does however is display the unmodified image. This snippit actually came from another post, in which apparently it worked. Doesn't for me though. Can anybody shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Last line: `to bottom`? I think that's a typo or smth.

Comment: @Chris No...that's proper syntax for a vertical gradient.

Comment: Interesting. thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

I'm guess that is this is the ***only*** code you are using then you've omitted to make the `html` element 100% tall so that the `body` can also be 100% tall.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.65) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-640-480-2.jpg);
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3nLdvL47/)

Comment: Ok so I guess it was working before, except the I had changed it to grey and white as my gradient colors, and the difference was so minute that I couldn't even tell. When I used the default colors as above, I could see it. But with that being said, what I have here wasn't exactly what I was going for. What I want to do is fade the image right out to nothing (so it just fades to white at the top and disappears...). Is that possible? Or does the image have to be formatted like that before it even gets added?

Comment: Also, how come I have to make the html height 100%? Wont it automatically set it's size based on the pages content? And by setting the body to 100%, it will take the size of the html block?

Answer (score 1):

if you remove `margin:0;` it works and gradient strippes image(because of that defaut margin body starts to fill `html`), or add `html{height:100%;}` it works.

html or body background mixe together if not set in both tags

some test so you can see and understand behavior

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract/10) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover;
}
html:hover body {
  margin: 4em;
  /* gradient is repeated and takes margin value as reference to repeat itself in html background */
}
```

if body has content or a valid height fixed, it works the same way

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract/10) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover;
}
html:hover body {
  margin: 4em;
  /* gradient is repeated body's height and keeps being repetead in html background*/
  height: 100px;
```

if you add html, body {height:100%;} then body has a valid height.

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract/10) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover;
}
```

and finally, if you give a background value to html, body will hold its own background within itself.

```css
html{background:lime;}
body {
padding:2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200/abstract/10) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover, cover;
}
```